# How do you call a wheel function every few wheel ticks or every few seconds?

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, mousewheel

I'm new to JavaScript and managed to make this wheel event but it keeps triggering which will get me on a different element and scroll past the next one since I'm using `nextElementSibling`.

I've tried throttling it but haven't been successful so far as I'm not good enough at JS yet and want to learn more.

```js
var scrollableElement = document.querySelector('body');

scrollableElement.addEventListener('wheel', findScrollDirectionOtherBrowsers);

function findScrollDirectionOtherBrowsers(event) {
  var delta;
  var aktiv = document.querySelector('.swap');

  if (event.wheelDelta) {
    delta = event.wheelDelta;
  } else {
    delta = -1 * event.deltaY;
  }

  if (delta < 0) {
    aktiv.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('swap')
    aktiv.classList.toggle('swap')
  } else if (delta > 0) {
    aktiv.previousElementSibling.classList.toggle('swap')
    aktiv.classList.toggle('swap')
  }
}
```

So the result should toggle .swap as soon as the function was triggered at least 2s ago or triggered 3-4 times. That is what I expect but maybe you might have even a better solution for me? It would be awesome! Thanks a lot for Your help! :)

Comment: Store the delta outside of `findScrollDirectionOtherBrowsers` (if this works try to implement it with a [closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)) and only "scroll" to the next element when the delta is big enough. Or count how often the function has been called.

Answer (score 0):

I just added a counter to make it happen. Works fine so far.

```
var scrollableElement = document.querySelector('body');
//new
var i = 0;

scrollableElement.addEventListener('wheel', findScrollDirectionOtherBrowsers);

function findScrollDirectionOtherBrowsers(event) {
  var delta;
  var aktiv = document.querySelector('.swap');

  if (event.wheelDelta) {
    delta = event.wheelDelta;
    //new
    i++;
  } else {
    delta = -1 * event.deltaY;
  }
  //new && i > 15 and set back to 0
  if (delta < 0 && i > 15) {
    i = 0;
    aktiv.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('swap')
    aktiv.classList.toggle('swap')
  //new && i > 15 and set back to 0
  } else if (delta > 0 && i > 15) {
    i = 0;
    aktiv.previousElementSibling.classList.toggle('swap')
    aktiv.classList.toggle('swap')
  }
}
```